# How can I access the variables inside objects stored in an Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am new to Java. I have created an arraylist of objects of custom class. Objects of the class contain private variables like *firstName*, *lastName*, etc. and public getters and setters to access it and set it.

I wanted to loop through the arraylist to check if *firstName* in any of the objects in the indexes of arraylist matches the name entered by user. How do I check that?

I know that the *get(i)* method when used on arraylist returns the element in the specific index. But I don’t want the complete object. I want the variable inside the object.

Comment: use a for loop then use arraylist.get(i).getVariable(); where getVariable() is whatever getter method you want

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get(i) to get the whole object, and then append to that the getter of the attribute that you want. `list.get(i).getLastName()` for instance.

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }

    // ... etc ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Person("Jim",       "Hawkins"));
    list.add(new Person("Alexander", "Smollet"));
    list.add(new Person("David",     "Livesy"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getLastName().equals("Livesy")) { // <-----
            System.out.println("Found matching name at index " + i);
        }
    }
}
```